# Returning elements of an XML file as a string

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm attempting to display XML content tags from a word document that the user uploads, but I'm not sure how to explicitly pull out the data, and then display it as a string.

I think the below SHOULD find the correct descendent (or element, either should work right?) and then allow me to create a string out of it and display it, but I can't get the file to recognise xdoc).  What I'm trying to return is located as "w.tag" in the bottom section of code.

Any ideas?

```
WordprocessingDocument _TempDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename, true);

                            //query to find particular descendants
                            var lv1s = from lv1 in xdoc.Descendants("table")
                                       select new
                                       {
                                           Header = lv1.Attribute("name").Value,
                                           Children = lv1.Descendants("tag")
                                       };

                            //Loop through results
                            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                            foreach (var lv1 in lv1s)
                                        {
                                            result.AppendLine(lv1.Header);
                                            foreach (var lv2 in lv1.Children)
                                            result.AppendLine("     " + lv2.Attribute("name").Value);
                                        }

                            //the label should contain the content controls of the document, using the class, XMLfromDocument                                                                                                                                           
                            labelContentControls.Text = fileUpload_Displayx(XMLfromDocument.GetContentControls(_TempDoc));

 public static XDocument GetXDocument(this OpenXmlPart part)
        {
            XDocument xdoc = part.Annotation<XDocument>();
            if (xdoc != null)
                return xdoc;
            using (Stream str = part.GetStream())
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(str))
            using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(streamReader))
                xdoc = XDocument.Load(xr);
            part.AddAnnotation(xdoc);
            return xdoc;

        }    

        //following method gets the structure of the content controls / XML in the document
        public static XElement GetContentControls( WordprocessingDocument document) 

        {

                XElement contentControls = new XElement("ContentControls",
                    document
                        .MainDocumentPart
                        .GetXDocument()
                        .Root
                        .Element(W.body)
                        .Elements(W.sdt)
                        .Select(tableContentControl =>
                            new XElement("Table",
                                new XAttribute("Name", (string)tableContentControl
                                    .Element(W.sdtPr).Element(W.tag).Attribute(
                                        W.val)),
                                tableContentControl
                                        .Descendants(W.sdt)
                                        .Select(fieldContentControl =>
                                                new XElement("Field",
                                                    new XAttribute("Name",
                                                        (string)fieldContentControl
                                                              .Element(W.sdtPr)
                                                              .Element(W.tag)
                                                              .Attribute(W.val)
                                                                   )
                                                            )
                                                )
                                     )
                            )           
            );




         // you cannot access the inner XML of the elemnt  directly, you must concatenate to the child elements.  
         // string contentTitle = string.Concat(W.sdtPr);


        //return W.tag;
                return contentControls;
```